# Cannot read property 'body' of undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

i have a register form in nodejs .

in this form i must check the phoneNumber is Exsist in database or not .

i use the `passportJs` for doing this .

but when i send the request it show me this error :

> Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

now i write here my code :

this is the passport for set in middlware :

```
     require('./passport/passport-local');
     app.use(passport.initialize());
     app.use(passport.session())
```

this is the `passport-local` file in my project :

```
    const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const UserModel = require('../models/users')

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

passport.use('local.register', new localStrategy({
    phoneNumberField: 'phoneNumber',
    passReqToCallback: true,
}, (req, phoneNumber, done) => {
    UserModel.findOne({ phoneNumber: phoneNumber }, (error, user) => {
        if (error) return done(error);
        if (!user) return done(error, false, req.flash('errors', 'This Phone Number exist . Please Choose the Other Phone Number'))

        const addUSer = new UserModel({
            name: req.body.name,
            family: req.body.family,
            phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
            password: req.body.password
        })

        addUSer.save((err) => {
            if (err) return done(err, false, req.flash('errors', 'امکان ثبت کاربر با این مشخصات وجود ندارد'));
            done(null, addUSer);
        });
    })
}))
```

and this is my controller :

```
   RegisterProcess(req, res) {

    var validateResult = validationResult(req);

    if (!validateResult.isEmpty()) {
        const errors = validateResult.array();
        let messages = [];
        errors.forEach(error => {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        req.flash('errors', messages)
        res.redirect('/auth/register');
    }else{
        this.register();
    }
}

register(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local.register', {
        successRedirect: '/admin',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/register',
        failureMessage: true
    })(req, res, next)
}
```

now whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???

**Edit : **

Full Stack Trace :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
at Strategy.authenticate (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/OnlineStore/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:71:29)
at attempt (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/OnlineStore/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:366:16)
at authenticate (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/OnlineStore/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:367:7)
at RegisterController.register (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/OnlineStore/app/http/controller/auth/RegisterController.js:36:11)
at RegisterController.RegisterProcess (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/OnlineStore/app/http/controller/auth/RegisterController.js:27:18)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/OnlineStore/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/OnlineStore/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at middleware (/home/mrcoder/Projects/Nodejs/OnlineStore/node_modules/express-validator/src/middlewares/check.js:15:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: which line triggers the error? `name: req.body.name,` ? Please post a full stacktrace and point to the problematic line in the code that triggers the error.

Comment: Make sure you're using some kind of body-parser or the express.json()

Comment: @EduardoFellipe i using the body-parser

Comment: @alfasin i update the question and put the stack trace

Comment: @kianoushdortaj and which one of the calls on your server triggers this error? the code you posted mentions at least 3 different passport calls + a middleware. Please focus the question and even though you want to provide as much information as possible it's important to post only relevant information otherwise it creates a "fog" of information which makes it more difficult to analyze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to parse data from a submitted html-form, you need an appropriate parsing-middleware. One common library is [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions). You can set it up as follows:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
// use bodyParser middleware for parsing application/xwww-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```